# How to format day part of DateTime in one digit?

Tags: c#

I have this: `var date = new DateTime(2009, 12, 5);`...

... and need this: `"Let's meet on December 5th."`

If I do this: `string.Format("Let's meet on {0:MMMM} {0:d}th", date)`...

... I get this: `"Let's meet on December 12/05/2009th"`

So how to output the day part (in one digit when lower than 10)?

(Please ignore the "1st"/"2nd"/"3rd"/"5th" problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers), try this:

```
string.Format("Let's meet on {0:MMMM} {0:%d}th", date)
```

or just make it one format specifier:

```
string.Format("Let's meet on {0:MMMM d}th", date)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string.Format("Let's meet on {0:MMMM} {1}th",date ,date.Day)
```

Comment: Works but not really taking advantage of the frameworks power and principles.